# Valid .cs file for COM dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm Java developer however `.Net` task assigned me for R&D. I'm using Visual Studio 2008. I created sample `.cs` file like as follow...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Example
{
    public class mathOperation
    {
        public int add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        public int subtract(int a, int b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to register `.DLL` file for `COM` operation generated by this `.cs` file.  I also set property `Register for COM interop` of project. And build it. Then created setup project but `.DLL` not registering for `COM` operation.

If this `.DLL` generated by this file is okay then can someone provide me link to how to create setup project to register such dll for `COM` operation

OR

I have to follow other things to create `.cs` file that can be used for `COM`

[image]

Comment: This example and the related links may help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx Your class will need to be decorated with attributes and will probably need an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an interface and decorate the types with the [GuidAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [ComVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [ClassInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.classinterfaceattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which are found in the [System.Runtime.Interopservices namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.InteropServices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Make sure that you run Visual Studio elevated because the registration for interop requires write access to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("516FED99-YOUR-GUID-HERE-C9EA0177568A")]
public interface  IMathOperation
{
    int Add(int a, int b);
    int Subtract(int a, int b);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("4354D883-YOUR-GUID-HERE-155A0DE30318")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MathOperation:IMathOperation
{

    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public int Subtract(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```